# Split array of dictionay to subarrays of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have array of dictionary

```
var array: [[String:AnyObject]]!
```

This array contains data like this:

```
[["timestamp" : 1462803636436 , "name" , "tttt" , ...... ],["timestamp" : 1526999236 , "name" , "aaaa" , ...... ]]
```

I want to split this array to subarrays by day :

Array 1 : today

```
[["timestamp" : "", .....],["timestamp" : "", ......]],....
```

Array 2 : yesterday

```
[["timestamp" : "", .....],["timestamp" : "", ......]],....
```

........

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a `[NSDateComponent : [[String:AnyObject]]]` that maps each day to an array of maps belonging to that day.
2. Iterate over your `array`.
3. Get the day of each `Dictionary` (see [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.htm) for details), and add it to the appropriate day's array in the new `Dictionary`.

   ```
   let dayMapping : [NSDateComponent : [[String:AnyObject]]] = []
   for submap in array {
       let day = getDay(submap["timestamp"])
       let dayArray = dayMapping[day]
       if dayArray == nil { //if there's no array for this day yet
           dayArray = []
           dayMappying[day] = dayArray 
       }

       dayArray.append(submap)
   }
   ```

The implementation of "getDay" will take me longer, I'll take a look at it tonight.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response
I want details of step 2 and 3

Comment: I understand now thanks you very much ;)

Comment: If you feel i've answered your question, please accept this answer :)

Furthermore, these maps seem like they should be structs/objects. Might be worth looking into

Comment: I need just to display data, no need search :)